# Gradle throws OutOfMemoryException on build

Tags: gradle, grails, out-of-memory, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to setup / clone an existing grails-project. I managed to install it fine on several windows/macos computers and also 3-4 servers running Ubuntu (ranging from 16.04 to 20.04). But the newest vServer I rented seems to have some problems regarding the gradle-build, as it always throws an OutOfMemoryException, no matter what I try to do.

I already tried increasing the maximum memory size, that grails / gradle are allowed to use but I still get the OutOfMemoryException. I managed to narrow it all down to gradle, which seems to have a problem with the vServer, which has no swap-memory - that's what I read out of everything gradle told me in the error-log:

```
There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue. 
Cannot create GC thread. 
Out of system resources. 
Possible reasons: 
- The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
```

Other than that, i noticed, that gradle uses around one to 1,5GB of memory before crashing - but I assigned him with up to 6GB using `-Xmx6G` (note that the system has 8GB availaible)

Maybe someone here can help me and tell me what I can do to solve this / get grails up and running (I tried everything I could find).

Attached I have the stacktrace of the (failed) build: https://pastebin.com/Kv2c4gu0

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The server has 8GB of memory; 4 cores;
I installed Java 1.8.0_252 through the openjdk 8
Gradle should be the version 4.4.1
Grails is installed with the version 4.0.1

Comment: According to the logs, you are using Gradle 3.5 and not 4.4.1. But that is probably not important. How did you configure the daemon (using `org.gradle.jvmargs`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved:
The vServer had 0b of swap-storage, which led to gradle/grails throwing an error of insufficient memory.

All I needed to do was create a swap-partition to have gradle compile.